# Can a GM TBI intake manifold be swapped on to a Chevy 350 that originally had a carburetor?

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-injection

I already have the TBI system running, but I'm currently using an adapter to the old Quadrajet spread bore.  I seem to recall issue with bolt locations or something.

Answer (score 0):

It might swap on. Some of the newer Gen 1 SBCs had different head to intake bolt patterns. I think they changed around 86 or 87 ... about the same time they went to roller camshafts. I believe if the heads have the center bolt valve covers, they have the newer bolt pattern.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping I could just pick up an aftermarket TBI intake, but I think this is a no go.  I thought someone must make a TBI swap intake, but I can't find one.  Finding an old used "in between year" intake might be tough, and not sure I'd want to toss my Edelbrock for such a thing.